# The creator of this fault did not specify a Reason

Tags: wcf, validation-application-bl

I have set validation attributes in the model of my WCF service

```
[MinLength(6, ErrorMessage = "Password should be at least 6 characters long")]
public String Password { get; set; }
```

When this fails I get the exception in the title instead of the error message that I specified in the attribute. I am using the Validation Application Block for WCF.

The method definition is like this:

```
[OperationContract]
[FaultContract(typeof(ValidationFault))]
User updateUser(User user);
```

Can someone tell my what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When this fails I get the exception

You should specify the type of Fault you expect, so use

```
catch (FaultException<ValidationFault> ex)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have added how my method definition looks like. Where do you think I should put your code?

Comment: @mitte put a try..catch around the client code that calls the service.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not handling validation falut. Use validation fault at operation contract .
You can refer this link..
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18667/Introduction-to-Validation-Application-Block-integ